# Web Crawler Amazon get span-Element

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm crawling amazon categories and I get the salesrank and the product URLs. Now I want to crawl the category and I get every information from the category span.

```
<span class="zg_hrsr_ladder">in&nbsp;<a href="https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_1">B&uuml;cher</a> &gt; <a href="https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/287480/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_2">Krimis & Thriller</a> &gt; <b><a href="https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/419954031/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_3_last">Deutschland</a></b></span>
```

This is an example code snippet and with following code

```
Elements category = htmlDocument.select("span.zg_hrsr_ladder");
```

I get everything inside the span. But I want only the text inside the a href "Bücher" "Krimis & Thriller" and "Deutschland". How can I get this information?

Comment: instead of crawling, use the api instead... http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the text inside the `<a>` element, so select anchors in your span (append " a" to the selector) and call [`text()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text--) and the resulting elements.

**Example Code**

```
String source = "<span class=\"zg_hrsr_ladder\">in&nbsp;<a href=\"https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_1\">B&uuml;cher</a> &gt; <a href=\"https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/287480/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_2\">Krimis & Thriller</a> &gt; <b><a href=\"https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/books/419954031/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_3_last\">Deutschland</a></b></span>";

Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(source, "UTF-8");

Elements category = htmlDocument.select("span.zg_hrsr_ladder a");

category.forEach(aElement -> {
    System.out.println(aElement.text());
});
```

**Output**

```
Bücher
Krimis & Thriller
Deutschland
```